# Android - page does not scroll

Tags: android

I have a page with this sort of a layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >       

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question_label"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your question: "
    />     

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    />     

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/please_wait"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Please wait while the discussion loads..."
    />     

    <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="20px" >        
    </ListView>

        <EditText  
            android:id="@+id/question_text"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:hint="@string/question_comment_hint"  
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"  
            android:lines="5"  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">  
        </EditText>

<Button  
            android:id="@+id/submit"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:text="@string/submit"  
            android:onClick="sendFeedback"  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">  
        </Button>               


</LinearLayout>
```

For some reason once the screen gets filled, it does not scroll down. Any idea why that might happen?

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Your question: " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/please_wait"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Please wait while the discussion loads..." />

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@+id/label"
            android:textSize="20px" >
        </ListView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/question_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="some text"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="5" >
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="sendFeedback"
            android:text="some tesxt" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

You have to use [Scrollview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) to scroll your view, try above code, hope it will work.

Comment: how come..!! check this out...you have closed your scrollView below the root linearLayout..correct your code

Comment: Just remember ScrollView can only have one direct child. I made that mistake >_<

Answer (score 1):

Use ScrollView below of linearLayout..definetely it will scroll the whole layout..

Comment: yeah I was thinking scrollview but wasn't sure how to implement it.  How would the syntax look like? Thanks!

Comment: use it below linearLayout...<ScrollView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

Answer (score 1):

embed your linear layout inside a scroll view

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Answer (score 1):

to have a scroll in list you will have to set its height for first display and then it will scroll automatically if it exceeds its length and for whole activity you should use scroll if it do not automatically scroll
or you may check it with setting the fix height for root linear layout